# Derivative of a constant integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the [integral](https://gyazo.com/36d65a7e00f70827710e6f4ef64036be):
$$\int_0^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_1^5\left(e^{\sqrt{x}}+x^3\right)dx\right)dx$$

This is zero right? Because the derivative of a constant is zero doesn't matter if its an integral, right?

Comment: That is correct: $\int_0^2 0{\rm d}x = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a poorly written question,
in that the variables of integration
are the same.

Here is my transcription of the problem:

$$\int_0^2 \frac{d}{dx} \left( 
\int_1^5 \left( e^{\sqrt{x}}+x^3\right) dx
\right) dx
$$

Since the inner integral
does not have any
unbound variables
(everything is either
"$x$" or a constant),
it is a constant.
Therefore,
its derivative
is zero.

The outer integral
is thus the integral of zero
and, as such, is also zero.